# Robotium - Trying to go click through menu

Tags: android, robotium

I have a menu in my app that i am trying to iterate trough. The menu consists of more than 10 items, but i only want to test the first 5 items (which i can select with either index or based on text).

I am looking for a generic solution that will

- select menu item 1
- do a text check
- select main menu
- select menu item 2
- do a text check
- select main menu
- etc

However i also need to execute this on multiple devices with different screen sizes, so it has to scroll to the menu item in case its not yet visible on screen.

I've tried using different solutions from these boards, but i have not been able to succeed yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a new style action bar menu or an old style? What have you tried so far?

Comment: As far as i know it is a new style, im opening the menu using the " android.R.id.action_bar_title" ID. Ive tried some solutions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094105/iterating-through-a-list-and-clicking-on-list-items-in-robotium?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is because of a bug in robotium that was fixed after the latest release. The issue in question is https://code.google.com/p/robotium/issues/detail?id=550

The latest code on github does have this fix in (see [here](https://github.com/RobotiumTech/robotium/blob/master/robotium-solo/src/main/java/com/robotium/solo/Clicker.java), so you could package the source yourself and use that as the latest version otherwise you are going to have to implement some methods that have the same functionality as that changed.

**Edit**
Robotium 5.0.1 is now available and should have the above fix in it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but how do i package and use this? Im kinda new to android/automated testing in general. Cheers

Comment: it should be as simple as running maven package from within the robotium folder that you will have downloaded, just like creating any jar via maven is, you will then just include the new jar in your project rather than the one you previously downloaded.

Comment: I have not been using maven at all before. I have downloaded the zip package, but im not sure how to use this to update my robotium jar.

Comment: what os are you on? you might be lucky. try going to that folder and then from the command line run mvn package

Comment: Or you can use your ide to open the project and try to build it from there

Comment: Im on windows 64 bit :). I can go to my test project and go to the build path and add like libraries there, currently it uses the robotium 4.3.1 jar. But i guess i need to somehow convert the zip to a jar file first?

Comment: You need to compile it first before you can turn it to a jar follow the instructions at: http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html then you can do the mvn package thing

Comment: Hey Paul, ive managed to succesfully install maven and packaged the extracted robotium project (Maven said build success). It now created a robotium-solo-4.3.2-SNAPSHOT.jar file. How do i import this now to my current testworkspace to replace the old robotium jar? Sorry for my noobness but im really new to this :)

Comment: if you find that jar file on your machine using search, just do it the exact same way you did the version of robotium you used before. I'm not sure what you used there so it is hard for me to give more details.

Comment: Ok ive replaced the jar file now in my project. There are some solo functions that are no longer recognized tho with the new jar. Like solo.finishOpenedActivities()

Comment: I just went to look at the code on github and noticed they have a new official release, go try out robotium 5.0.1