# .getCurrentListViews() method is not available in Robotium for Iterating through list textview.

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, listview, robotium

I want to access the list view child textview value in **Robotium** test class, through this documentation http://controlingquality.blogspot.in/2011/08/playing-with-android-application.html i see these lines to access textview 
`ListView lvResults = solo.getCurrentListViews().get(0);` or `ArrayList vTextViewResults = solo.getCurrentTextViews(lvResults);`
First line is getting the first list used on screen, and second line it getting all TextView controls in ArrayList, but **.getCurrentListViews()** method is missing. Version i'm using **robotium:robotium-solo:5.5.2**

Some link also reffered [Iterating through a List and clicking on list items in Robotium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094105/iterating-through-a-list-and-clicking-on-list-items-in-robotium#) https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robotium-developers/UY69TKCF5Fw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some surfing in net came to know, that from 4.0 (not sure from which version exactly) some methods are replace by generic method.

**Prevoius** code to get the first list used on screen

```
ListView list = solo.getCurrentListViews().get(0);
```

Now to get the same in updates lib it should be

```
ListView list = solo.getCurrentViews(ListView.class).get(0);
```

So for Iterating in list TextView it should be

```
//TODO: Getting all TextView in the List
 for (TextView txt : solo.getCurrentViews(TextView.class, solo.getCurrentViews(ListView.class).get(0))) {
        Log.i("ListItem", txt.getText().toString());

    }
```

Helpful [Link](http://controlingquality.blogspot.in/2013/04/get-number-of-views-on-android-screen.html)